# How to remove zsh alias?

Tags: zsh, alias

I have an alias which is predefined by an oh-my-zsh plugin.

`-> % alias gcm
gcm='git checkout master'`

I'd like to remove it, i.e. I'd like `alias | pcregrep "\bgcm\b"` return 1.
I've tried with `alias gcm=''` but after that the alias is still existent.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can remove an alias simply using:

```
$ unalias gcm
```

Comment: will this unalias it forever or only for this session?

Comment: @meteors Each session starts with no aliases, then they get created via your scripts - so, it depends on what you have in them.

Comment: Note that if you have a global alias, you need to quote the alias name like so: `unalias 'gcm'`. Otherwise, the alias is getting expanded before executing the `unalias` command.

Answer (score 11):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/786957) is correct but if you're adding the `unalias gcm` line to your `.zshrc` file, it must be done AFTER oh-my-zsh is sourced, or else it will be overwritten by the zsh defaults.

It would look something like the below in your `.zshrc` file:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# must unalias all ZSH defaults here AFTER we source the above
unalias gcm
alias gcm="whatever you want"
```

Comment: Since the last alias wins by default, the `unalias` line in this example is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

For removing git aliases in zsh git plugin you can comment them out in `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh` which is default installation location for git plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all alias defined

```
unalias -m '*'
```