# How do I change or remove an alias in Zsh in MacOS?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh

I am trying to install a build tool on my Mac called [please](https://please.build/); however it seems the word "please" is already aliased to "sudo" and I don't know where that alias is being set.

I'm using [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) which means I have a `~/.zshrc` file instead of a `~/.bashrc` file. But I can tell you that nowhere in my `~/.zshrc` file nor in my `~/.bash_profile` file are any aliases being set on the word "please."

Still, when I type `please` in the terminal I see this:

```
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user] file ...
```

And when I type `which please` it just says this:

```
please: aliased to sudo
```

Are there other locations I'm not thinking of where aliases can be defined? How do I get rid of this annoying alias?

Comment: Your question isn't "why is...", it is "how do I remove an alias", which is a good thing: We can't answer "why" questions, generally. Some dev decided to, that's why. But we can answer "how do I...". I've edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: That's fair, although I certainly have a lingering "why" in my mind, since usually the reason an alias shows up in the first place is because you've defined it in one of those files that I mentioned above. Since it's not defined as such I still wonder what else is causing it to show up.

Comment: Also, this question may already have an answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229886/how-do-i-change-delete-alias-in-os-x-permanently Give it a look-see and let us know. If that does not answer your question, please edit this one to clarify how it is different.

Comment: It is indeed different. Did you read mine? Did you read the one you linked to? The answer you linked to was essentially "remove the alias command from your `~/.bashrc` file." I stated pretty clearly in my question above that I do not have a `~/.bashrc` file; instead I have a `~/.zshrc` file because I use ZSH, and moreover that there are no alias commands in my `~/.zshrc` file at all. Word of advice: please read questions thoroughly before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: I'm not going to get into a spitting contest. I read your question. Shells share many common elements, and there are plenty of results on the question "how do I remove an alias in macos". How Zsh differs may or may not be salient. Further, you specifically noted that the alias was not apparent in the .zshrc file. Further, ZSH apparently does use the "unalias" command referenced in the linked question, and further searching reveals this question which is specific to ZSH and recommends that very command: https://superuser.com/questions/786956/how-to-remove-zsh-alias

Comment: This one offers another method: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161973/clear-or-disable-aliases-in-zsh

Comment: I know neither `zsh` nor MacOS but in Linux there may be global rc scripts in `/etc`. I would try `grep -rl "alias please" /etc 2>/dev/null`. Not sure if it helps on Mac.

Comment: I discovered the reason why this is a problem. It's in the [oh-my-zsh code](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/lib/misc.zsh#L26) here; they explicitly set the alias.